# Android get an error when i use simple class extended AsyncTaskLoader into LoaderManager

Tags: android, loader

I'm trying to use Loaders into android and i'm newbie into this feature, i created simple class with extended from `AsyncTaskLoader` as this code:

```
public class StringLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<RobotViewModel>> {
    public StringLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public List<RobotViewModel> loadInBackground() {
        List<RobotViewModel> model = new ArrayList<>();
        RobotViewModel       temp  = new RobotViewModel();
        temp.setMessage("hello");
        temp.setMessageType(SV.RobotMessageType.SENT_BY_ROBOT.ordinal());
        model.add(temp);

        return model;
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(List<RobotViewModel> data) {
        super.deliverResult(data);
    }
}
```

now i want to use this class into `LoaderManager` in `Activity`

```
private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<RobotViewModel>> loaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<RobotViewModel>>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<List<RobotViewModel>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new StringLoader(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<RobotViewModel>> loader, List<RobotViewModel> data) {
        adapter.setData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<RobotViewModel>> loader) {
        adapter.setData(Collections.<RobotViewModel>emptyList());
    }
};
```

unfortunately i get error on this line of code:

```
return new StringLoader(getApplicationContext());
```

[image]

Comment: You've got the wrong `AsyncTaskLoader` class imported in your `StringLoader` class. You need `android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader`.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh thanks sir. problem resolved